# I didn't played for a long time or I haven't play for a long time

Tags: meaning, word-choice, sentence-construction, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Today I played archery with my friends that I seldom used to play before this, so the context with my friends was :

A: Last time I went there was like 7
years ago

B: Same, I also didn't play for a long
time

So I wondered if my usage (didn't play for a long time) was proper and correct since I meant that few years before today I didn't play archery. I hope my text is clear.

Answer (score 3):

We don't speak of *playing* archery, but *doing* or *taking part in* it. You play sports that take the form of games, like tennis, football or cricket.

You could answer your friend

> I haven't done archery for a long time either.

*Didn't played* and *haven't play* are both incorrect. You could say

> After I left school I didn't play tennis for a long time, but I started again when I moved to [town].

...but if you are starting again today, you can say *I haven't played for a long time*.